# Custom JsonConverter (System.Text.Json) producing invalid json

Tags: c#, json, .net-core, system.text.json, jsonconverter

This is the class I want to custom serialize:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string Key {get; set;}
    public IEnumerable<string> Value {get; set;}
}
```

If I've got a list of it, normal serialization would produce the following output:

```
[
    {
        "Key": "MyKey1",
        "Value": [
            "Value1",
            "Value2"
        ]
    },
    {
        "Key": "MyKey2",
        "Value": [
            "Value3",
            "Value4"
        ]
    }
]
```

What I want is to remove the property-names from the json-result like so:

```
[    
    {
        "MyKey1": [
            "Value1",
            "Value2"
        ]
    },
    {
        "MyKey2": [
            "Value3",
            "Value4"
        ]
    }
]
```

So i decided to implement a custom JsonConverter like so:

```
public class MyClassJsonConverter : JsonConverter<MyClass>
{
    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, MyClass value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        //custom code goes here
        writer.WriteStartArray(value.Key);

        foreach (var val in value.Value)
            writer.WriteStringValue(val);

        writer.WriteEndArray();
    }
}
```

But this produces invalid json:

```
[
    "MyKey1": [
        "Value1",
        "Value2"
    ],
   "MyKey2": [
       "Value3",
       "Value4"
    ]
]
```

How to resolve this?

Comment: You should write start and end elements

Comment: Why don't you consider using a`Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>` data structure?

Comment: `Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>> p = new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>();`

`p.Add("MyKey1", new List<string> { "Value1", "Value2" });`

`p.Add("MyKey2", new List<string> { "Value3", "Value4" });`


`Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(p));`

Output:

`{"MyKey1":["Value1","Value2"],"MyKey2":["Value3","Value4"]}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `WriteStartObject()` before writing the array and `WriteEndObject()` after

```cs
public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, MyClass value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
{
    writer.WriteStartObject();

    //custom code goes here
    writer.WriteStartArray(value.Key);

    foreach (var val in value.Value)
        writer.WriteStringValue(val);

    writer.WriteEndArray();
    writer.WriteEndObject();
}
```

Then the following code

```cs
var list = new List<MyClass>
{
    new MyClass { Key = "MyKey1", Value = new[] { "Value1", "Value2" } },
    new MyClass { Key = "MyKey2", Value = new[] { "Value3", "Value4" } }
};

var options = new JsonSerializerOptions();
options.Converters.Add(new MyClassJsonConverter());
var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(list, options);
```

gives you the expected JSON

```
[
    {
        "MyKey1": [
            "Value1",
            "Value2"
        ]
    },
    {
        "MyKey2": [
            "Value3",
            "Value4"
        ]
    }
]
```